# Line is getting clipped, would like to draw beyond

Tags: wpf

The line that I am drawing is getting clipped, I am not able to draw beyond and across elements in different containers.

Sample code:

```
    <Grid Width="30" Height="30" Background="Black">
<Line Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="1"  X1="1" Y1="1" X2="100" Y2="100" ClipToBounds="False"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ClipToBounds` is working a little bit strangely because it depends on the container whether it uses it or not.

Wrap your `Line` into a `Canvas` and it will work:

```
<Grid Width="30" Height="30" Background="Black">
   <Canvas>
      <Line Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="1"  X1="1" Y1="1" X2="100" Y2="100" 
            ClipToBounds="False"/>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

You can read more about this here: [ClipToBounds="Maybe"](http://drwpf.com/blog/2007/12/28/cliptoboundsmaybe/)